# Output an ordered collection (using LINQ) into a listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I want to order a text file using LINQ by date and output all columns into a listbox.

For example the input file is:

Name,Age,DOB,Male
Mary,28,01/01/1991,False
Anne,29,06/06/1989,False
John,18,06/07/2000,True

class Name
    {
        public double Age { get; set;}

```
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Male { get; set; }



public Name()
{

}

public Name(string name, double age, DateTime date, string male)
{
        Course = course;
        Amount = amount;
        Date = date;
        Male = male;
}


}

private IEnumerable<Name> ReadName()
    {
        List<Name> dataCollection = new List<Name>();
        using (var f = new StreamReader(@"R:\Data.txt"))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var data = line.Split(',');
                dataCollection.Add(new Name(data[0], Convert.ToDouble(data[1]),Convert.ToDateTime(data[2]),  data[3]));
            }
        }
        return dataCollection;
    }

private void btnDOBOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstByDate.Items.Clear();
            IEnumerable<Name> names = ReadName();
            var DateOrder = name
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                            .ToList();

            lstByDate.DataSource = DateOrder;
        }
```

Name  Age  DOB  Male
John  18  06/07/2000  True
Mary  28  01/01/1991  False
Anne  29  06/06/1989  False

The current output in the listbox is:
Form1.Name
Form1.Name
Form1.Name

Comment: what's the current result ?

Comment: result is  
Form1.Name   
Form1.Name   
Form1.Name

Comment: Can you post the `Name` class?

Comment: You probably wanted to write `var DateOrder = names (...)`, the `IEnumerable` you just got from the `ReadName()` method. You should also, probably, specify the `DisplayMember` of the ListBox or override `ToString()` in the `Name` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing on listbox the string representation of your Name Class? If yes you just have to override ToString method in your Name class to display what information you want

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox`'s display collections of `ListItem`s, and those have  Text and Value properties that control what they display. You could project your collection into an anonymous type before databinding, then set the the DataValueField and DataTextField to your computed properties. It could look something like this:

```
var DateOrder = names.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                     .Select(x => new { Text = $"{x.Name} {x.Age} {x.DOB} {x.Male}", Value = x.Name })
                     .ToList();

lstByDate.DataSource = DateOrder;
lstByDate.DataValueField = "Value";
lstByDate.DataTextField = "Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ICompare :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person(FILENAME);
            person.Sort();
        }

    }
    public class Person : IComparable 
    {
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public int Age { get;set;}
        public DateTime DOB { get;set;}
        public string sex { get;set;}

        List<Person> dataCollection = new List<Person>();

        public Person() { }
        public Person(string filename)
        {            
            using (var f = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                string line = string.Empty;
                int rowCount = 0;
                while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (++rowCount > 1)
                    {
                        var data = line.Split(',');
                        dataCollection.Add(new Person() { Name = data[0], Age = Convert.ToInt32(data[1]), DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(data[2]), sex = data[3]});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return this.DOB.CompareTo(((Person)obj).DOB);
        }

        public void Sort()
        {
            dataCollection.Sort();
        }
    }

}
```